# Какая лучшая книга/видео/звуковая дорожка/сайт/курсы/etc. по основам программирования?

Tags: книги

Чувствую что не сильно хорошо знаю основу, хоть и занимаюсь программированием больше 3 лет.

Язык не важен, только не Паскаль.
Знаком с с, с++, c#, php, basic, JavaScript, sql

Comment: Кстати, `~101 = 1111 1111 ... 1111 1010`.

Comment: Думаю, что лучше курса лекций в хорошем вузе нет. Хотя, сейчас есть online-курсы, может быть они и ничего.

Comment: Кстати, ~101 = вот поэтому и спрашиваю=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое чувство, что Вам требуется не книга по программированию, а по архитектуре ЭВМ. То есть, чтобы понять, все операции булевой логики, стоит изучать более низкоуровневые языки (Assambler, С.. )

Как раз чтобы понять где уместно какую операцию использовать хорошо помог бы Assembler, если Вы поймете основы работы ЭВМ, как там происходят операции, то все последующие языки не должны вызвать у Вас проблем, так как все крутится на железе.

Еще хороший вариант, если есть время и возможность, поиграться с микроконтроллерами и как раз попробовать пописать для них на низкоуровневых языках. Там и поймете что и где использовать, как построены операторы на низком уровне, какая команда сколько тактов занимает.

Думаю книг можете найти уйму по данной теме.Вот пример.

[Архитектура компьютера  Э. Таненбаум, Т. Остин](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20032936/)

Но думаю что такие книги лучше читать в оригинале, так как в переводе очень много ошибок.

Так что разбирайтесь с двоичной системой, поймите как она работает и думаю сразу же станет легче писать, при этом более эффективно.

Удачи Вам.

Answer (score 1):

Head First Java - книга очень подробная, с примерами и практическими заданиями. Начиная от знакомства с программированием (переменные, операторы) и вплоть до ООП. В принципе поняв основу программирования можно перескакивать на любой язык, пока не углубляться они все работают по одному принципу (почти).